# is it possible to access record's detail page from force.com sites

Tags: force.com-sites

i have 1 table on visualforce page & it contains a links which redirects to record's detail page,
i have used this visualforce page in force.com site,
so the issue is when i click on link in table from inside salesforce it redirects to record's detail page
but when i try to do same thing from force.com site,it is asking for authentication even i have given all require object & feilds permission(public access settings).

so from force.com sites we can access the record's detail pages or not??

Comment: Is it standard or custom object? And how looks the domain of your site ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the record detail page as that is an internal page that is only accessible to authenticated users.  Unauthenticated users can only access the Visualforce pages that you have configured to be available to the site.

The way I would handle this is to create a Visualforce page for the sobject type in question and add the `<apex:detail/>` tag to the new page - that will display the same information as the record detail page.  You would also need to update the markup that is generating the table to output a link to your new Visualforce page rather than the internal record view page.